# CakePHP FormHelper: how to ADD classes to default without replacing

Tags: php, css, forms, cakephp

CakePHP v.2.5.x

I want to modify the defaults for a form to add my own css classes to the wrapping `div`. I know how to do this, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it *without* overwriting CakePHP's defaults. For example, with no `$options['class']` the system adds input-specific classes dynamically, like `.error` etc. In other words, I want the defaults AND my additions, not just my additions.

```
    echo $this->Form->create('Listing'); 
    $this->Form->inputDefaults(array(
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'default-class'
            )
        )
    );

    //will result in .default-class because of default above
    echo $this->Form->input('title', array(
        )
    ); 
    //will result in .adhoc-class because we just overrode the default
    echo $this->Form->input('address',
        array(
            'div'=>array('class'=>'adhoc-class'),
        )
    );
```

In the above examples, I'd like the first to have the default class that I set, PLUS CakePHPs dynamic classes. In the second, I'd like the `.adhoc-class` to be added to those same classes. Is this possible? In case this isn't already clear, it's kind of a two-part question: how to make the default class settings "additive" and secondly how to make the individual input settings additive.

Answer (score 0):

from the API : http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-FormHelper.html#_input
according with http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-HtmlHelper.html#951-970

it seems not possible for add a class at your "default class"